# change colour of column in google charts

Tags: google-visualization

How do you change the colour of a column in google charts. I have this `drawGraph` function:

```
function drawGraph(){
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'House 1')
  data.addColumn('number', 'House 2')
  data.addColumn('number', 'House 3')
  data.addColumn('number', 'House 4')

  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2016, 01, 20),
      180,
      150,
      186,
      176,
    ],
    [new Date(2016, 01, 19),
      100,
      150,
      200,
      175,
    ],
    [new Date(2016, 01, 11),
      10,
      11,
      20,
      17,
    ],
    [new Date(2016, 01, 07),
      55,
      51,
      123,
      100,
    ],
  ])

  var options = {
    title: 'House Points',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Date'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Points'
    }
  }

  var material = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('edhp_housepoints'));
  material.draw(data, options);
}
```

I want to set the colour for House 1 to 4 how would I do that?

I have tried a few things but none of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colours for each column can be set in the options hash like so:

```
var options = {
  title: 'House Points',
  hAxis: {
    title: 'Date'
  },
  vAxis: {
    title: 'Points'
  },
  colors: [
    "#f0c514",
    "#eb7f25",
    "#eb4b33",
    "#22b05a"
  ]
}
```

Comment: you can also specify colors within the `series: {0:{color: 'black'}}`